# Despite the connect() method returning 0 (enum), the function specified in the connection is not called

Tags: godot, scene

The subject script:

```
    extends ColorRect

onready var subject = get_parent().get_node('Page1')

func _ready():
    var error = subject.connect('set_timer', self, 'ad')


func ad():
    print('signal connected')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the function `ad` to run when the signal `set_timer` is emitted (not when it is connected). I cannot find an standard `set_timer` signal (for reference `Timer` nodes have a `timeout` signal, perhaps that is what you want?). I'd suppose it is a custom signal you created. If you are not emitting that signal, Godot will not call `ad` for you.

To emit a custom signal, in the script attached to the subject (`Page1`), call `emit_signal("set_timer")`. See [Godot documentation on `emit_signal`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-emit-signal).

The following code is taken from [Godot documentation on Sigals](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/signals.html):

```
extends Node2D


signal my_signal


func _ready():
    emit_signal("my_signal")
```

If you try to emit a signal that does not exist, you will get an error in the console like this one:

```
emit_signal: Can't emit non-existing signal "set_time".
```

However, in your case, I believe the signal exist, otherwise, when connecting you would have got the following error:

```
connect: In Object of type 'ColorRect': Attempt to connect nonexistent signal 'set_time' to method 'ColorRect.ad'
```